Tow to Implement a Dropdown for a Tableau Parameter in JavaScript Embedding API
I'm embedding a Tableau dashboard into a web page using the Tableau Embedding API. I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu to allow users to interact with a parameter called "Moeda" (a text parameter in Tableau, not a filter).
I've already implemented a similar dropdown for filters, but I'm struggling to figure out how to properly load and update a parameter in the dashboard via the dropdown. My goal is to:
Display the available values for the "Moeda" parameter as options in a dropdown.
Update the parameter in Tableau when a user selects a new value from the dropdown.
What I've Tried:
Here’s what I’ve done so far in JavaScript based on the Tableau Embedding API documentation:
async function loadMoedaParameter() {
  const sheet = viz.workbook.activeSheet;

  try {
    // Get the list of parameters from the workbook
    let parameters = await viz.workbook.getParametersAsync();

    // Find the "Moeda" parameter
    let moedaParam = parameters.find((p) => p.name === "Moeda");

    // Check if the parameter exists
    if (!moedaParam) {
      console.error("Parameter 'Moeda' not found!");
      return;
    }

    // Create a dropdown for the "Moeda" parameter
    let dropdown = document.createElement("select");
    dropdown.style.border = "none";
    dropdown.style.fontFamily = "Space Grotesk";
    dropdown.style.outline = "none";
    dropdown.style.width = "100%";
    dropdown.style.height = "40px";
    dropdown.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    dropdown.id = "optMoeda"; // Dropdown ID

    // Populate the dropdown with allowable values of the parameter
    moedaParam.allowableValues.forEach((value) => {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = value.formattedValue;
      option.value = value.value;
      dropdown.appendChild(option);
    });

    // Set the current value of the dropdown
    dropdown.value = moedaParam.currentValue.value;

    // Add an event listener to update the parameter in Tableau when the user changes the selection
    dropdown.addEventListener("change", async (e) => {
      const selectedMoeda = e.target.value;
      try {
        // Update the Tableau parameter
        await viz.workbook.changeParameterValueAsync("Moeda", selectedMoeda);
        console.log("Moeda changed to:", selectedMoeda);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error changing the Moeda parameter:", error);
      }
    });

    // Append the dropdown to the container in the HTML
    const moedaContainer = document.getElementById("Moeda-container-desktop");
    moedaContainer.appendChild(dropdown);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error loading the Moeda parameter:", error);
  }
}

I’m calling this function after the dashboard has been fully loaded using:
viz.addEventListener(TableauEventType.FirstInteractive, loadMoedaParameter);

The container where I want the dropdown to appear is:
<div id="Moeda-container-desktop"
     style="
       width: 300px;
       height: 50px;
       background: #FFFFFF;
       border-radius: 35px;">
</div>``` 

I get an empty dropdown. No matter what I try. The rest of the code is working perfectly, i have filters working perfectly, but for this parameter, I can't make it work.
If you have something simpler than this, or any suggestion I'd appreciate


Can you show an example of how you got it working for filters?
